# Evaluating $\int_0^1 \frac {x^3}{\sqrt {4+x^2}}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

How do I evaluate the definite integral $$\int_0^1 \frac {x^3}{\sqrt {4+x^2}}\,dx ?$$ I used trig substitution, and then a u substitution for $\sec\theta$.

I tried doing it and got an answer of: $-\sqrt{125}+12\sqrt{5}-16$, but apparently its wrong.

Can someone help check my error?

Comment: It would be hard to spot the error without seeing more of your steps.

Comment: Please use TeX. You can find TeX commands from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Displaying_a_formula).

Comment: Wow, I never knew you can use TeX. Thanks Mario for fixing it. I'll be sure to use the commands from now on.

Comment: Okay @Travis , I'll post a pic from dropbox of my solution

Comment: @XihaiLuo You're welcome!

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tkspdlwb1f6i9hr/20150129_000328.jpg?dl=0

Comment: ^my attempt at the problem

Comment: @XihaiLuo  I can't quite read your handwriting,but it's clearly an ugly computation by hand.

Comment: @XihaiLuo  Alternatively you could also try  $ u = 4+x^2$

Comment: @XihaiLuo, See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124550/what-is-the-integral-of-frac-sqrtx2-4xdx

Comment: @labbhattacharjee That's a somewhat different integral,but the same basic substitutions.Worth a look for the user.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234, Whenever, we have $$\int x^{2n+1}(\sqrt{a^2+x^2})^m\ dx$$ we can try this

Comment: Even $u=\sqrt{4+x^2}$ seems like a reasonable substitution.

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone for helping me!

Answer (score 7):

A way to compute this is as follows:
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \frac {x^3}{\sqrt {4+x^2}}\mathrm d x &=\int_0^1\frac{4x+x^3-4x}{\sqrt{4+x^2}}\mathrm d x\\
&=\int_0^1x\sqrt{4+x^2}\mathrm d x -2\int_0^1\frac{2x}{\sqrt{4+x^2}}\mathrm d x\\
&=\left.\frac{1}{3}(4+x^2)^{3/2}\right|_0^1-4\left.\left(4+x^2\right)^{1/2}\right|_0^1\\
&=\frac{5\sqrt{5}-8}{3}-4\left(\sqrt{5}-2\right)\\
&=\boxed{\color{blue}{\dfrac{16-7\sqrt{5}}{3}}}
\end{align*}

Comment: GREAT solution, never would have thought of it! I always envy guys who are so good at basic algebra that they can solve any problem with a slight of hand like this.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 Thanks, there are some skills that one learn by observing another people.

Comment: Holy moly what a solution

Answer (score 3):

By the change of variable $x^2+4=t$, we have $2x\,dx=dt$:
$$\int_0^1\frac {x^3}{\sqrt {4+x^2}}\,dx=\frac12\int_4^5\frac{t-4}{\sqrt t}\,dt=\frac13t\sqrt t-4\sqrt t\Big|_4^5=\frac{16-7\sqrt5}3.$$

Answer (score 1):

Following your way:
$$\begin{align}\int_0^1 \frac {x^3}{\sqrt {4+x^2}}\,dx &=8\int_0^{\arctan(1/2)}\tan^3\theta\sec\theta{\rm d}\theta\tag{$x=2\tan\theta$}\\&=8\int_1^{\sqrt{5}/2}(t^2-1){\rm d}t\tag{$t=\sec\theta$}\\&=8\left(\frac{t^3}3-t\right)\Bigg|_1^{\sqrt5/2}\\&=\frac83\left(\frac{5\sqrt5}8-1\right)-8\left(\frac{\sqrt5}2-1\right)\\&=\large \frac{16-7\sqrt5}3
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\int_0^1\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{4+x^2}}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{x^22x}{\sqrt{4+x^2}}dx=\int_0^1\frac{(x^2+4-4)(4+x^2)'}{\sqrt{4+x^2}}dx$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, let $x=2\sinh t$, and use the fact that $\cosh^2t-\sinh^2t=1,~\sinh't=\cosh t$, and $\cosh't=\sinh t$. You will finally arrive at $\displaystyle\int\sinh^3t~dt=\int(\cosh^2t-1)~d(\cosh t)=$ $=\displaystyle\int(u^2-1)~du$, which is trivial to evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{4+x^2}} d x&=\int_0^1 x^2 d\left(\sqrt{4+x^2}\right) \\
& =\left[x^2 \sqrt{4+x^2}\right]_0^1-\int_0^1 \sqrt{4+x^2} d\left(x^2\right) \\
& =\sqrt{5}-\left[\frac{2}{3}\left(4+x^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\right]_0^1\\&=\frac{1}{3}(16-7 \sqrt{5})
\end{aligned}
$$