# What is the integral of $\frac{\sqrt{x^2 +4}}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

I use trig substitution then get to this step but then I get stuck:
$\int \frac{2\sec ^3\theta}{\tan \theta}d\theta$
anything I do seems to further complicate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\sec^3 x/\tan x$ is equal to $\sin x/(\cos^2 x (1-\cos^2 x))$ and you can find that how to substitute it.

Comment: See also: [Integral of $\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/286118).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}} x$$
$$=\int \frac{2\sec^2\theta\sqrt{4\tan^2\theta+4}}{2\tan \theta}$$
$$=2\int \frac{\sec^3\theta}{\tan \theta}$$
$$=2\int \frac{1/\cos^3\theta}{\sin \theta/\cos \theta}$$
$$=2\int \frac{1}{\sin \theta \cos^2 \theta}$$
$$=2\int \frac{\sin \theta }{\sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \theta}$$
$$=2 \int \frac{\sin \theta }{(1 - \cos^2 \theta) \cos^2 \theta}$$
$$=2 \int \frac{-1}{(1 - u^2 ) u^2 }$$
$$=2 \int \frac{-1}{u^2 - u^4  }$$
Rest should be easy....

If you want a different way to do this problem, try $x=2\sinh \theta$

If you want to do this another way, try Euler Substitutions!

Comment: "try $x=\cosh \theta$" Hmmm, rather $x=2\sinh \theta$.

Comment: If $x=2\cosh\theta$ then $\sqrt{x^2+4}=$... a mess.

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

$$\frac{\sqrt{4+x^2}}x=\frac{x\sqrt{4+x^2}}{x^2}$$

Write $\sqrt{4+x^2}=u\implies4+x^2=u^2,x\ dx=u\ du$

$$\int\frac{\sqrt{4+x^2}}xdx=\int\frac u{u^2-4}u\ du=\int\frac{u^2-4+4}{u^2-4}du=\cdots$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Rewrite the integrand just in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$, and manipulate the expression so that one can substitute $u = \sin \theta$ or $u = \cos \theta$.

> Write $$2 \int \frac{d\theta}{\sin \theta \cos^2 \theta} = 2 \int \frac{\sin \theta \, d\theta}{\sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \theta} = 2 \int \frac{\sin \theta \, d\theta}{(1 - \cos^2 \theta) \cos^2 \theta}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, let $x=2\sinh t$, and use the fact that $\cosh^2t-\sinh^2t=1,~\sinh't=\cosh t$, and $\cosh't=\sinh t$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\overbrace{\color{#66f}{\large\int\frac{\root{x^{2} + 4}}{x}\,\dd x}}
^{\ds{x=t^{1/2}\ \dsc{\imp}\ t=x^{2}}}\ =\
\overbrace{\half\int\frac{\root{t + 4}}{t}\,\dd t}^{\ds{\dsc{t}=\dsc{\xi^{2} - 4}\ \imp\ \dsc{\xi}=\dsc{\root{t + 4}}}}\ =\
\int\frac{\xi^{2}}{\xi^{2} - 4}\,\dd\xi
\\[5mm]&=\int\pars{1 + \frac{1}{\xi - 2} - \frac{1}{\xi + 2}}\,\dd\xi
=\xi + \ln\pars{\verts{\frac{\xi - 2}{\xi + 2}}}
=\root{t + 4} + \ln\pars{\verts{\frac{\root{t + 4} - 2}{\root{t + 4} + 2}}}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large\root{x^{2} + 4}
+\ln\pars{\verts{\frac{\root{x^{2} + 4} - 2}{\root{x^{2} + 4} + 2}}}}
+ \mbox{a constant}
\end{align}